# Cleaning a dataset, but in the descriptive statistics the information about erased data remains

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
Animal Father Weight
1      John   55
2      John   60
3      Bruce  55
4      Peter  66
5      Sand   35
6      Sand   45
7      Loki   35
8      Loki   35
```

I want to delete all the rows where to `Father` column appears only once. To do this I did the following:

```
New.dt= dt[!table(dt$Father)[dt$Father] <= 1, ]
```

Ok, it's work perfectly:

```
Animal Father Weight
    1      John   55
    2      John   60
    5      Sand   35
    6      Sand   45
    7      Loki   35
    8      Loki   35
```

But when I do some statistic for the new `dataset(New.dt)`, the information about the deleted fathers remains. Like this:

```
summary(New.dt$Father)

John  Bruce Peter Sand Loki
  2     0     0     2    2
```

This for all statistics, but I don't want to use this phantom information. How I do to exclude these information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that the column `Father` is of type `factor`.
If you convert it to character first you shouldn't encounter these problems:

```
dt$Father <- as.character(dt$Father)
New.dt= dt[!table(dt$Father)[dt$Father] <= 1,]
summary(New.dt$Father)
```

You can avoid `factor` right from the beginning:

- If you create your data with `data.frame` you can set `stringsAsFactor = FALSE`.
- If you read your file from a csv file (or similar) using `read.table`you can also set `stringsAsFactor = F`.

Comment: Assuming the data was read from file, the best would be not to load it as a factor in the first place. The infamous `stringsAsFactor = FALSE`... or use smarter reading functions like the ones from `readr`.

Comment: Thank you, I added this in my answer